# React-Bootstrap FormControl with Icon

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to add an icon to an input field using React Bootstrap and react-fa (font-awesome). Is there a prop I can set on the Form Control component? The code below I've inserted an icon but it's obviously above the input not inside.

```
<form>
    <FormGroup
        controlId="formBasicText"
        validationState={this.getValidationState()}
        className="login-form">
        <ControlLabel>Email address</ControlLabel>
        <Icon spin name="spinner" />
        <FormControl
            type="text"
            value={this.state.value}
            placeholder="Your email"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            className="login-input" />
        <ControlLabel>Password</ControlLabel>
        <FormControl
            type="text"
            value={this.state.value}
            placeholder="Your password"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            className="login-input" />
        <FormControl.Feedback />
    </FormGroup>
    <Button bsStyle="success btn-raised btn-block" bsSize="large" onClick={this.closeModal}>Let's Go</Button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 17):

There is a quick and easy "out of the box" solution to the problem.
Just wrap your `<Form.Control>` in an `<InputGroup>` and add a `<InputGroup.Text>`, which will contain the icon you wish to include. The content of the `<InputGroup.Text>` is not restricted, it can be text, symbols, other components, etc.

The syntax has changed and the newer version doesn't have `<InputGroup.Prepend>`

I am including an example of my code, which uses a react-fontawesome icon inside a text input field.

```
                 <Form.Row>
                    <Form.Group as={Col}>
                        <InputGroup>
                                <InputGroup.Text>
                                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon="search" />
                                </InputGroup.Text>
                            <Form.Control
                                type="text"
                                placeholder="Search here.."
                            />
                        </InputGroup>
                    </Form.Group>
                </Form.Row>
```

It looks like this:
[image: searchbar-example]

An official example by react-bootstrap can be found [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/docs/forms/input-group).
Hope that helps! Cheers!

PS: libs used
"react-bootstrap": "2.9.0-beta.1" (bootstra 4.3)

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't look like `react-bootstrap` supports `font-awesome` icons out of the box according to the [docs](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#forms-validation). However, it appears you can cheat. It's possible to put a `<FontAwesome>` control inside the `<FormControl.Feedback>` `react-bootstrap` control and have it display the icon inside the text box.

I tested this using `react-bootstrap` version 0.31.0. I also used the `react-fontawesome` NPM package ([here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-fontawesome)) to actually add the icon. You would do something like the following:

```
<ControlLabel>Email address</ControlLabel>
<FormControl
    type="text"
    value={this.state.value}
    placeholder="Your email"
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    className="login-input"
/>
<FormControl.Feedback>
    <span style={{ top: '5px' }}>
        <FontAwesome name="check" spin key="icon" />
    </span>
</FormControl.Feedback>
```

That addition of a `<span>` and inline style were needed to properly center the icon. I suspect that was necessary because I am breaking some rules for how the `<FormControl.Feedback>` renders icons. That wasn't needed when I used the `<Glyphicon>` instead. Unfortunately, there is no built in spin/rotate feature with the `<Glyphicon>`.

A bit of a hack, so use with caution.

Answer (score 2):

I use bootstrap only and package icons (react-icons)

```
<div className="input-group col-md-4">
                <input className="form-control py-2 border-right-0 border" type="search" defaultValue="search" id="example-search-input" />
                <span className="input-group-append">
                <div className="btn btn-outline-secondary border-left-0 border">
                <FaBeer/>
                </div>
                </span>
            </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately, React Bootstrap doesn't have prop for icons for input component out of the box. Alternatively, React Semantic UI does have a prop icon for the input. See documentation here: https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/input/

If you still want to use React Bootstrap, you can create a div element within the InputGroup, and style this element to `position: absolute` and use `top` and `right` css elements to make adjustments as needed. Here's the work around:

```
//Your JSX file

      <InputGroup>
        <FormControl
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search..."
          onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
        />
        <div className="search-icon">
          <i class="fas fa-search" />
        </div>
      </InputGroup>

//CSS

.search-icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  z-index: 9999; /*this will keep the icon appearing all time, even when on input::focus*/
}
```

Comment: The question is how to do it with react-bootstrap. Not which framework is able to add an icon..